# Mark of the web help required

Tags: html

When I am opening my html page in IE 6 it is giving a info bar on the page , the error is ***"To help protect your security Internet explorer has restricted this webpage from running
scripts or ActiveX controls that could access your computer.Click here for options...."*** and my page is blank.When I am ***allowing block content*** the page is coming. I have searched in google and find a solution.The solution is need to add in the page.[link of the page.](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/19513-ie-security-warning-activex-controls-scripts.aspx)

But still it is showing the info bar.Please help.

Comment: Why the heck are you using IE6?

Comment: I need to make it compatible with IE6

Answer (score 1):

Go to `tools/internet options`.

and in the `security` tab click on the `trusted sites` and then click on `sites` and add your website there.

Comment: I can not change the security setting of all the system where it will run.I need to by pass this with the coding.

Comment: It is a browser's security feature. and you cannot disable it with coding.

Answer (score 0):

What ActiveX component are you using? is it media player or something? if it can be replaced by other plugins, (flash in case of media files) the security bar wont pop up.
More details are needed about what the page contains.
Else Rahim's answer is correct.

Comment: So its Google Chrome frame plugin or something on those lines? If its just the canvas plugin from the HTML5 spec, I searched and found this JS : http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/wiki/Instructions which might help. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

have you included the html5 shiv?

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Needed for IE.